# Http Range in GWT for a resumable download

Tags: java, gwt, http-headers, download, resume-download

I want to find out a way for fetching HTTP_RANGE (sending by http request from browser or download manager) in gwt. I found it in php (`_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']`) but i couldn't find a solution for java.

The work that i want to do, is a way for resumable file download using gwt.

Answer (score 0):

GWT does not deal with file downloads so I suppose you're rather talking about servlets.

You can get header values using the `ServletRequest` passed to your servlet.